# How to reset settings of far manager?

Tags: far

I wanted to change the tab size in far manager which was set to 8 spaces by default so I made changes in editor settings and viewer settings but now I am seeing my text like this as shown in the image below how can I change it ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/toTRE.png

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**: Go to `Options » Editor settings` and uncheck the `Show white space` option.

[image]

**Option 2**: Delete the **entire** Far Manager profile ( `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Far Manager\Profile`)

**Option 3**: Type `far:config` in the command line. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see only non-default values. Scroll to the Editor.* values and Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to toggle to the default value.
[image]